# Type-casting to boolean

Tags: php, casting, boolean

Can someone explain me why this:

```
var_dump((bool) 1==2);
```

returns

```
bool(true)
```

but

```
var_dump(1==2);
```

returns

```
bool(false)
```

Of course the second return is correct, but why in the first occasion php returns an unexpected value?

Comment: Order of operations is getting you here...

Comment: You could do this in the following way

var_dump((bool) (1==2));

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It's actually not as strange it seems. [`(bool)` has higher precedence than `==`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), so this:

```
var_dump((bool) 1==2);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var_dump(  ((bool) 1)   == 2);
```

or this:

```
var_dump(true == 2);
```

Due to [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), the `2` also essentially gets cast to `bool` (since this is a "loose comparison"), so it's equivalent to this:

```
var_dump(true == true);
```

or this:

```
var_dump(true);
```

Comment: ...yet another reason to try to always use `===`

Comment: @xDaizu  This doesn't have anything to do with using ===.  The following returns false, which is still unexpected if you don't understand operator precedence:
(bool) 1===1 
Simply use == and === when each is appropriate for the given situation.  Not just based on some "always do this" rule.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc: You're right that `(bool) 1===1` has a similar problem to `(bool) 1==2`, but `===` does eliminate half of what's confusing here: the type juggling rules are complicated and counterintuitive. I'm not aware, personally, of any situation where `==` is appropriate, but I guess that's a matter for a different question . . .

Comment: @ruakh with regard to the question, I don't find the expression 1==2 confusing at all and I'm aware of several situations where == works very well.  Again, == vs. === is irrelevant to finding a solution to the given problem.  Type juggling has nothing to do with the problem that the OP is presenting.  It's just confusing this with a separate issue.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc: Re: "I don't find the expression 1==2 confusing at all": But the OP's code didn't have the expression `1==2`, it had the equivalent of `true==2`. Do you really claim to find it obvious that `true==2` should be `true`? Re: "I'm aware of several situations where == works very well": Ah, but are you aware of any situations where it's better than `===`? If not, then a "never use `==`, only `===`" rule is actually a pretty good one.

Comment: The OP code has var_dump((bool) 1==2);  It's the equivalent of true == 2 because of the OPERATOR PRECEDENCE. Just like ((bool) 1===1) is equivalent to (true === 1)... That's certainly not obvious the way it's written, even with ===.   Also, true==2 isn't hard to understand for me, and makes perfect sense for some applications.  However, if anyone doesn't understand == well enough to use it, then I can understand why they would want to always use ===.  So, to each his own.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc If OP used === in the first statement, he's going to get bool(false) as he wanted, because true is not the same as 2.

Comment: @DanielWu yes, you found one of the many ways to change an expression to evaluate false.    The poster wasn't asking "how can I make this expression return false."  If the poster just wanted to find a way to get false, I'm sure they  could do that by themselves

Answer (score 21):

Because in the first example, the cast takes place before the comparison. So it's as if you wrote

```
((bool) 1)==2
```

which is equivalent to

```
true == 2
```

which is evaluated by converting `2` to `true` and comparing, ultimately producing `true`.

To see the expected result you need to add parens to make the order explicit:

```
var_dump((bool)(1==2));
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/gFK9b)**.

Answer (score 7):

I use this way:

```
!!0 (false)
!!1 (true)
```

Comment: As the headline asks for typecasting this answer is correct and can be used in almost any language. This construct is great for languages like JavaScript where you need a real "true" or "false", but not to keep the original value. BTW, typecasting with (bool) is a little bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

filter_var - Filters a variable with a specific filter

```
$boolvar = filter_var('true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

boolval - Get the boolean value of a variable PHP 5 >=

```
$boolvar = boolval ('true');
```

And literally with a ternary operator but I can't recommend it

```
$boolvar = ($string === 'true')  ? true: false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the statement ((bool) 1==2) will always return true because it will always execute the code like below flow:

First, it will execute

```
(bool)1
```

and (bool) 1 will return true.

Now since (bool)1 is true at second step your statement will be like

```
true ==2
```

Since if we will typecast 2 into boolean it will return true, at final state your statement will be like

```
true == true
```

Which will obviously return true.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the bracket you had to do this in the following way.

```
var_dump((bool) (1==2));
```