# Can ($a == 1 && $a == 2 && $a == 3) ever evaluate to true?

Tags: php

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true) which was intended for javascript, it has spawned off numerous [spin-offs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383521/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-evaluate-to-true-in-java) for various different languages. I'm curious if the following can ever evaluate to true in PHP:

```
($a == 1 && $a == 2 && $a == 3)
```

To follow up a bit more, it seems [simply setting `$a = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399280/4875631) will yield the desired result (This was not the case for javascript, due to the way type casting works in both languages). A few answers (in javascript) worked with `===` as well, so in PHP with typechecking (`===`), can the following ever yield true?

```
($a === 1 && $a === 2 && $a === 3)
```

Comment: If you could search SO for the javascript explanation, why not search for the php explanation on SO?

Comment: My dupe link explains php's strict and loose comparisons ad nauseum.  Plus the php manual is also a decent reference.  I'll spend a little more time searching for something better if that one doesn't do it for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894395/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa You keep just linking how type casting works...I Get it. The challenge becomes, how do we get a variable to equal 1, 2, and 3. It's not a clear cut solution, and simply slapping a downvote/close vote on this doesn't help. I *highly suggest* you check the linked question where I got my inspiration for this question.

Comment: @mickmackusa The answers to that question do not directly answer this question. I don't think It's a duplicate.

Comment: @cpburnz I don't even think they indirectly answer this question.

Comment: @FrankerZ After seeing Taha Paksu's answer and if you squint hard enough you could argue that you could derive his answer from the comparison table for `==` from the other question. But that's quite the stretch because you might as well close questions as duplicates for RTFM then.

Comment: I don't mean to keep stirring but here is another related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380452/type-casting-to-boolean  The 3 close votes will probably age away.  You may as well grant the green tick so that the system deems this question resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can (a ==1 && a== 2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: @TaylorSen Not a valid dupe target. It was pretty clear in the Moderator note (72 upvotes), that we should *please also refrain from posting more answers in different languages*. That question is clearly intended for javascript, and this for PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
$a = true;
echo ($a == 1 && $a == 2 && $a == 3);
```

and it echoed `1`.

Because of the type casting and not type checking, 1, 2, 3 will be treated as `true` when compared to a boolean value.

**Answer to the edit:** No it can't be done.

**Hackish method** which @FrankerZ commented about:

Zero byte character = **0xFEFF**

http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/65279

http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html

```
$var  = "1";
$var = "2";
$ var = "3";

echo ($var  === "1" && $var === "2" && $ var === "3") ? "true" : "false";
```

This code runs with this character because the name `$ var` and `$var`  seems to be valid for the PHP compiler and with the appropiate font, it can be hidden. It can be achieved with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: PHP is a funny language.

Comment: @FrankerZ to make it less funnier, there is an `===` operator.

Comment: As a PHP programmer, I tend to avoid two things: dynamic type-juggling, and non-typed variables

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Interesting. Because window is the global javascript "object", defining properties on that can yield the results where even `(a === 1 && a === 2 && a === 3)`. It's amazing what javascript can do, when you put your mind to it.

Comment: Yep I was trying to set an getter to a variable on PHP and if I succeed, this would be done in PHP too ;)

Comment: @TahaPaksu I'm going to give this about a day for other people to see if this is indeed possible. I'll accept this answer if there are no other replies.

Comment: I'm a little sad this got so many down-votes, thought this would have been an interesting question to research, to see if this was possible in PHP. Unfortunately, it seems like variables can't be considered getters. I was able to get this working with a true value for: [`($a->a === 1 && $a->a === 2 && $a->a === 3)`](https://www.tehplayground.com/NJwPLrFYIcFFvFzb)

Comment: Yes it can also work with `$a() === 1 && $a() === 2 && $a() === 0` but not with variables itself without modifying the core `int` type I guess.

Comment: @TahaPaksu It does appear that it may be possible to accomplish this with the Unicode characters such as 0 width spaces, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274520/4875631).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not strictly in keeping with the question, this can be done if the ints are wrapped in quotes:

```
<?php

class A {
    private static $i = 1;
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)self::$i++;
    }
}

$a = new A();

if($a == '1' && $a == '2' && $a == '3') {
    echo 'yep';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a case where strict comparison would ever yield true. [===](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.h#L782) operator compares the types first, so there's no way to use any magic method wizardry.

For curiosity the closest i could get is to slightly modify the setting and hack the variable in a tick function. Since ticks are only incremeted per statement, we have to break the comparison to multiple statements for this to work.

```
$a = 1;
register_tick_function(function () use (&$a) {
    ++$a;
});
declare(ticks = 1) {
    $a === 1 or exit(1);
    $a === 2 or exit(1);
    $a === 3 or exit(1);
}
echo "a = $a\n";
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/VHm52).