# How does just-in-time compiler optimizes Java parallel streams?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, jvm, java-stream, jit

Some time ago an interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383521/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-evaluate-to-true-in-java) had been asked:

```
Can (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) evaluate to true in Java?
```

I decided to prove that it is possible using Java 8 Stream API (parallel streams, to be precise). Here is my code that works in very rare cases:

```
class Race {
    private static int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(0, 100_000).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            a = 1;
            a = 2;
            a = 3;
            testValue();
        });
    }

    private static void testValue() {
        if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

And then I thought, maybe it's because of potential JIT compiler optimizations? Therefore, I tried to run the code with the following VM option:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE
```

I disabled the JIT and the number of success cases has increased significantly!

How does just-in-time compiler optimize parallel streams so that the optimization might impact the above code execution?

Comment: You forgot to make `a` `volatile`, that's what the difference here is, not streams

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Streams don't matter. The same effect can be observed with just two simple threads like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48383616/3448419).

When `a` is not `volatile`, JIT compiler can optimize (and it actually does!) consecutive assignments.

```
    a = 1;
    a = 2;
    a = 3;
```

is transformed to

```
    a = 3;
```

Furthermore, JIT compiler also optimizes `if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)` to `if (false)` and then safely removes the entire `testValue()` call as dead code.

Let's look into the assembly generated for the lambda.
To print the compiled code I use `-XX:CompileCommand=print,Race::lambda$main$0`.

```
  # {method} {0x000000001e142de0} 'lambda$main$0' '(I)V' in 'Race'
  # parm0:    rdx       = int
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x00000000052eb740: sub     rsp,18h
  0x00000000052eb747: mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp  ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - Race::lambda$main$0@-1 (line 8)

  0x00000000052eb74c: mov     r10,76b8940c0h    ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'Race')}
  0x00000000052eb756: mov     dword ptr [r10+68h],3h  ;*putstatic a
                                                ; - Race::lambda$main$0@9 (line 10)

  0x00000000052eb75e: add     rsp,10h
  0x00000000052eb762: pop     rbp
  0x00000000052eb763: test    dword ptr [3470000h],eax
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x00000000052eb769: ret
```

Besides the method prologue and eplilogue there is just one instruction that stores value 3:

```
  mov     dword ptr [r10+68h],3h  ;*putstatic a
```

So, once the method is compiled, `System.out.println` never happens. Those rare cases when you see "Success", happen during the interpretation, when the code is not yet JIT-compiled.

Comment: Why can't `a = 1; a = 2; a = 3;` be optimized to `a = 3;` if `a` is `volatile`?

Comment: @shmosel Strictly speaking, it *may* be optimized in this particular case, though such an optimization is not what developers or compiler writers typically expect from `volatile` variables. In HotSpot JVM a volatile store is always a write to the main memory.

Comment: @shmosel it would require additional logic (considering the impact on memory visibility), just to serve an uncommon case, as developers already try to avoid too many accesses on `volatile` variables (usually), as they know they have a performance impact.