# Something I want to make permanent in java

Tags: java, string

If I have

```
String[] arr = new String[6]
```

what code can I use to make it permanent? I haven’t tried anyway way yet and I’m finding it difficult to get this specific information.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your question clear and you'd better paste your code here .

Comment: That is invalid Java code

Comment: it seems you want `final` which cannot be modified.

Comment: What do you mean by "permanent"? It's very unclear what you're asking at the moment, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please write a valid code!

Comment: Permanent like store in database or file?

Comment: u mean [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) ?

Comment: I just want a large number of strings that can’t be removed

Comment: Removed from what? We can't read in your mind. Edit your question, and elaborate.

Comment: I suspect the best way would be to make it private and have your code not update any of the values.  Setting it to final will not stop you from overwriting values, only from changing it to be a different array.  If other classes rely on that array, you could create a method `String[] getArr(){return {"a", "b", "c"};}`

Comment: What is the overall goal?  It's easy to never change the value in your code, you would not need to lock it locally

Comment: @phflack yes you can but you can not control other developers, can you? Even you yourself may change it accidentally!

Comment: @Shadow You can lock down classes you create, but if the other developer has direct access to all of your code, then they can just edit out the locks.  Trying to control other developers is probably off-topic for this site, but may be more apt for [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)/[IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @phflack We want values to be locked otherwise what is Application of `final` or similar key words in other languages like `const`. yes any one can edit code  intentionally but developer can protect its values from his mistakes and others mistakes by locking it to ease debugging.

Comment: If you are always accessing the Strings individually, it may be better to give them each names and declare each as `private static final String STRINGNAME = "String";`

Comment: If it is a list of Strings that you need locked, you could use a final unchangeable list

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with arrays is that they are hard to lock

Using `final String[] arr = {"a", "b"};` blocks attempts to set `arr` to a new value, but using `arr[0] = "c";` is still valid

Instead, it's easier to just keep it private and never change it in your code

---

If this list is to be sent to other places and must not be modified, you can use an [unmodifiableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) object instead

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("a");
arr.add("b");
arr = Collections.unmodifiableList(arr);
```

It isn't completely safe, as [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37628/5475891) will still be able to modify the values ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385779/5475891)), but it should suffice for avoiding errors while coding

Comment: So by adding <a> or <b> to the code how does that determine the number but still lock it ?

Comment: Would I put the number after “a” so it would be “a20” ?

Comment: @Wru In the last line, `Collections.unmodifiableList(arr)` creates a locked list.  If you're trying to convert an array to a locked list, you could use `String[] arr = ...; List<String> locked = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(arr));`

Comment: @Wru What do you mean by number after a? `"a"` and `"b"` are just example Strings added to the list, they can be whatever you want _(and as many as you want)_

Comment: String[] arr = 30; List<String> locked = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(arr)); 30 being the array

Comment: `String[] arr = 30;` won't work, but the rest should be fine. Perhaps you meant `String[] arr = new String[30];`?