# Should singleton class public methods be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a singleton wrapper class abstracting elasticsearch APIs for my application.

```
public class ElasticSearchClient {    

    private static volatile ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClientInstance;

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    private static elasticConfig ; 

    /*
    ** Private constructor to make this class singleton
    */
    private ElasticSearchClient() {
    }

    /*
    ** This method does a lazy initialization and returns the singleton instance of ElasticSearchClient
    */
    public static ElasticSearchClient getInstance() {
        ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn = elasticSearchClientInstance;
        if (elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn == null) {
            synchronized(lock) {
                elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn = elasticSearchClientInstance;
                if (elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn == null) {
                    // While this thread was waiting for the lock, another thread may have instantiated the clinet.
                    elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn = new ElasticSearchClient();
                    elasticSearchClientInstance = elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn;
                }
            }
        }
        return elasticSearchClientInstanceToReturn;
    }

    /*
    ** This method creates a new elastic index with the name as the paramater, if if does not already exists.
    *  Returns true if the index creation is successful, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean createElasticIndex(String index) {
        if (checkIfElasticSearchIndexExists(index)) {
            LOG.error("Cannot recreate already existing index: " + index);
            return false;
        }
        if (elasticConfig == null || elasticConfig.equals(BatchConstants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
            loadElasticConfigFromFile(ELASTIC_CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
        }
        if (elasticConfig != null && !elasticConfig.equals("")) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection elasticSearchHttpURLConnection = performHttpRequest(
                    ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL + "/" + index,
                    "PUT",
                    elasticConfig,
                    "Create index: " + index
                );

                return elasticSearchHttpURLConnection != null &&
                       elasticSearchHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
            } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error("Unable to access Elastic Search API. Following exception occurred:\n" + e.getMessage());
          }
        } else {
            LOG.error("Found empty config file");
        }
        return false;
    }

private void loadElasticConfigFromFile(String filename) {

    try {
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(filename);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        LOG.info("Successfully parsed elastic config file: "+ filename);
        elasticConfig = jsonObject.toString();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Cannot read elastic config from  " + filename + "\n" + e.getMessage());
        elasticConfig = "";
    }
}

}
```

I have multiple threads that use ElasticSearchClient as mentioned below

```
Thread1
ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient = ElasticSearchClient.getInstance()
elasticSearchClient.createElasticIndex("firstindex");

Thread2
ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient = ElasticSearchClient.getInstance()
elasticSearchClient.createElasticIndex("secondindex");

Thread3...
```

As per me the Singleton class is thread safe but I am not sure what will happen if more than one thread starts executing the same method of a singleton class. Does this have any side-effect?

Note: I am aware of that the singleton class above is not reflection and serialization safe.

Comment: What might happen if multiple threads called `createElasticIndex("sameIndex")` concurrently? Well, quite a lot of things since there is no synchronization but one thing could be that multiple put requests are generated.

Comment: Multiple put requests are expected. Because they are writing to a different indexes in the elastic search. My whole concern is will one thread create any sort of data corruption for data of some other thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular implementation

```
if (checkIfElasticSearchIndexExists(index)) { //NOT THREAD SAFE
            LOG.error("Cannot recreate already existing index: " + index);
            return false;
        }
        if (elasticConfig == null || elasticConfig.equals(BatchConstants.EMPTY_STRING)) { //NOT THREAD SAFE
            loadElasticConfigFromFile(ELASTIC_CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
        }
        if (elasticConfig != null && !elasticConfig.equals("")) { //NOT THREAD SAFE
```

There are 3 points that could cause racing conditions.

So per se

> Should singleton class public methods be synchronized?

There is no such rule - if those would be thread safe, then no additional synchronization is needed. In your case, those are not thread safe thus you must make them threas safe eg. making

```
public synchronized boolean createElasticIndex
```

If you are concenr eg about writing concurrently to single index, then don't - it is an ElasticSearch task to handle concurent writes properly (and trust me ES will handle that smoothly)

Whats not thread safe (pointed out 3 places)? Having concurrent T1 and T2:

1. `checkIfElasticSearchIndexExists(index)` If T1 and T2 will use the same index name, both will pass this check (I only assume it is a rest call - that is even worst)
2. `elasticConfig == null || elasticConfig.equals(BatchConstants.EMPTY_STRING)` Well on first runt T1 and T2 will both pass this test and both will load config from file - probably wont have impact, but still it is a racing condition
3. `if (elasticConfig != null && !elasticConfig.equals(""))` The same scenario as 2 + if due to memory model, if elasticConfig is not `volatile` it can be read as "not null" before `loadElasticConfigFromFile` will inilatize it fully.

2 and 3 can be fixed with either double-check-locking (like you do in `getInstance()` or I would rather move it to instance initialization block - constructor would be the best for that I think.

As for better undestanding of that phenomenon you can check [why a==1 && a==2 can evaluate to true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48383616/1527544)

1 however is bigger problem due to delay between call and response you got a wide window where 2 threads can query for the same index and get exact same response - that index does not exist and try to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. This makes sense.